Как увеличить подпись на цветной шкале рисунка
подскажите пож-та, имеется следующий код отображающий результаты кластеризации - необходимо увеличить подпись на цветной шкале на рисунке справа. Не могу разобраться какой параметр в коде за него отвечает (или куда надо дополнительно прописать размер подписи).
pallet=plt.get_cmap('rainbow') # spectral, rainbow, terrain
nDim=2
for alg in ['UMAP','tSNE']:
    if alg=='UMAP':
        reducer = umap.UMAP(n_neighbors=30, min_dist=0.1, n_components=nDim, random_state=42)
        mapOut = reducer.fit_transform(inpMtx)
        mapOut_umap = mapOut
    elif alg=='tSNE':
        tsne = manifold.TSNE(n_components=nDim, init='random', random_state=42, perplexity=30, verbose=0)
        mapOut = tsne.fit_transform(inpMtx)
        mapOut_tsne = mapOut
    figHdb = plt.figure(figsize=(17,15))
    axHdb = figHdb.add_subplot(111)
    axHdb.set_title(r'$'+alg+'$ 2D-visualization',fontsize=16)
    axHdb.set_xlabel('t-SNE измерение 1',fontsize=18)
    axHdb.set_ylabel('t-SNE измерение 2',fontsize=18)
    im3 = axHdb.scatter(mapOut[:,0], mapOut[:,1], s=6, cmap=pallet, c=clusterLabels)
    figHdb.colorbar(im3, ax=axHdb)
    figHdb.tight_layout()
    figHdb.savefig(alg+'out_2D.png')

пример рисунка

